# Is it possible to VIEW Google Contacts Customized Fields on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, contacts, google-sync, google

We have some Google Contacts with Customized Fields (not customized email titles) such as:

- Certifications Attained:
- Years Experience in this Field:
  Among other customized fields that show up toward the bottom of the contacts details in Gmail.

What we need however, is to be able to VIEW (or see) these Contacts' Customized Fields (and their answers) on the iPhone or iPad.

We have tried syncing with the recently made available option of CardDAV, but that only shows Relationship fields (in addition to their regular contact info such as phone number, address, etc...).

Can anyone suggest how we can VIEW this contact data on our iPhones/iPad's? I just can not seem to figure this one out.